# installation failed reverting ./composer.json to its original content. laravel #1

Tags: laravel

While installing `nexmo/laravel` I am getting following error.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myLaravel1>composer require nexmo/laravel 1.0.0-beta3

Problem 1
- Can only install one of: nexmo/client[1.0.0-beta3, 1.0.0-beta4].

- Can only install one of: nexmo/client[1.0.0-beta4, 1.0.0-beta3].

- Can only install one of: nexmo/client[1.0.0-beta3, 1.0.0-beta4].

- nexmo/laravel 1.0.0-beta3 requires nexmo/client 1.0.0-beta3 -> satisfiable
by nexmo/client[1.0.0-beta3].

- Installation request for nexmo/laravel 1.0.0-beta3 -> satisfiable by nexmo
/laravel[1.0.0-beta3].

- Installation request for nexmo/client (locked at 1.0.0-beta4, required as
@beta) -> satisfiable by nexmo/client[1.0.0-beta4].
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\myLaravel1> composer require nexmo/laravel

Comment: update your composer and then again try to install package ..

Comment: @Nisanth Hi are you here

Comment: yes sir comments are blocked due to lack of comments

Answer (score 0):

To install the specific version you need to use `package_name:version` syntax

```
composer require nexmo/laravel:1.0.0-beta3
```

Apart from that `nexmo/client` is locked at version `1.0.0-beta4`. So you need to that version. So try this instead :

```
composer require nexmo/laravel:1.0.0-beta4
```

Comment: Not getting you.